# Using GCM to send notifications on app, returns InvalidRegistration error

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a notification using GCM on my android device, but I always get InvalidRegistration error.

Here is the PHP code that is supposed to send the notification:

```
<?php
define('API_ACCESS_KEY', 'API KEY HIDDEN');

$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id']);

// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'TestMessage',
    'title'     => 'TestTitle',
    'subtitle'  => 'TestSubtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'TestTicker',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;
?>
```

This is how the registration is done:

```
private void registerInBackground() {
new AsyncTask<Void, Object, String>() {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String msg = "";
        try {
            if (gcm == null) {
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
            }
            regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
            msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

            //Here I save the registration ID, and when I try to use it manually, by running the PHP script above, I get the error.
            sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

            // Persist the registration ID - no need to register again.
            storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
        }
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(context, msg + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}.execute(null, null, null);
```

After running the application, and calling the method that registers the app, I get a registration ID. Then, when I type `localhost/app/sendNotification.php?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx` I get

```
{"multicast_id":8460288429151356251,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Invalid Registration ID Check the formatting of the registration ID
>   that you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration ID
>   the phone receives in the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
>   intent and that you're not truncating it or adding additional
>   characters. Happens when error code is InvalidRegistration.

So basically you are making an error in sending the DeviceID received by the phone to the server. Make sure your code does not alter the deviceId in any way. You have not posted the code for accepting the Id's. There is a mistake in that part or the storing of the DeviceId's. I don's think there is any error in the code you have posted as the errorLog show's Invalid Registration

Comment: That was it, I had a little problem, now I fixed it. I get `success:1` now, I've got another question, how do I start receiving messages in the app now? They're not coming

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html   check the part for Receive a downstream message

Comment: I am also getting smilar problem how did you resolve it @Val

Comment: How did you fixed?? I am getting same problem

Comment: Check the format of the registration token you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with Firebase Notifications. Do not truncate or add additional characters.

While you sending this device to send from Rest client it may chance to change the format.

For me `:A` changed to `%3A`. But it is fine when receiver end it decrypts it. 
But for test make sure don't copy device_id from URL parameters from Rest Client.  
You print the device_id and copy it for testing.

Comment: I am facing the same issue after uploading the app to store before that even archive build works fine. can any one help?

Answer (score 11):

If you are retrieving token from db make sure the data type for the column is either text or a very long varchar like 200. The token is more than a 100 characters long so it might be getting cut in half to be stored in the db

Comment: Thank you! I thought that column of 128 char length would be enough, but it wasn't. Expanding it had solved my problem

Comment: That's it! Thanks too much

Comment: I had put my field to 64 chars, what was I thinking?! Good stuff

Answer (score 0):

i am solved this problem by sending device registration id, like

```
<?php
require_once('loader.php');

// return json response 
 $json = array();

$registatoin_ids = array("APA91bHhzESU4GQKwS_I-sMMpAPZ44GbC0wvDAO-Dch87_jwJzaB1gK5PPeaGmt6vFZx2Bvd6AC8EkYDl6PurNUDO6zLoxX50q7gLc8GMOLGcwmQgiWwSZS-PPOFn1MpA5hz_TFQ6S-4tstLO");
$message = array("product" => "shirt");

$result = send_push_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
echo $result;
?>
```

in register.php file.
U will get this device registration id from google cloud.