# Firebase cloud messaging php script returning invalid registration

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I researched online and tried various methods to fix this problem however it did not solve the problem. This is the error i get in my php script

```
{"multicast_id":6412971464416964071,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

I am using authorisation key which is the server key.

push_notification.php

```
<?php 
function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
         'data' => $message

        );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = ********',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
   $ch = curl_init(); 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);           
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fcm");
$sql = "Select Token From users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$tokens = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tokens[] = $row["Token"];
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
$message = array("message" => " FCM PUSH NOTIFICATION TEST MESSAGE");
$message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
echo $message_status;
?>
```

There is a valid token in my database. However it shows invalid registration. How do i fix this?

Comment: Verify yout Sender id  in android and Authorization: key in php script

Comment: @bindal yup i verified my sendor id and authorisation: key (server key) and it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If it's invalid registration,

> check the format of the registration token you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with Firebase Notifications. Do not truncate or add additional characters.

Source: [Downstream message error response codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes)

If that recommended action doesn't work for you, here are additional things that you can do:

- [Verify ID Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). It mentioned about the need to verify the integrity and authenticity of the ID token and retrieve the `uid` from it.
- You may want to also check this suggested solution in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37425563) wherein it states that if you retrieve token from db, you make sure the data type for the column is either text or a very long varchar like 200.

Comment: I used the same token id to send notification from the firebase console to my android emulator and it works fine. Also in my database for the token it is varchar 500. I am still having the same problem (InvalidRegistration) in my php script.

Comment: Check to make sure you are not submitting any empty string registration id