# Php push notification not working

Tags: php, android, cordova

I am trying to use Push Notifications in Cordova.
I also added the Push Notification Plugin to my project, and entered there my Sender ID.
I am using the Cordova Device plugin to get the Device ID
This is the code I use to send the data to the server.

```
var id = device.uuid;
    alert(id);
    document.getElementById("f1").value = id;
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
```

and this is the PHP code:

```
    <?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'KEYGOESHERE' );
$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;

?>
```

Everytime I run the script, I recieve this error:

```
{"multicast_id":5616818555748303283,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

Can you please help me ? I have no idea why this is not working, I am not altering the Device ID string in the code.
Is there something I'm missing from the back/front-end part ?

Comment: This should help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29706107/1485183

Comment: I read that topic,but the only advice I found there was to check if the code was not altering the ID.
My code is not altering the string

Comment: The Id I get from the code is 16 characters long, is that the ID I have to send, or there is another way to retrieve the correct ID

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem while working with Push-Notification.

You are taking `Web API Key` from console.

Now take key `Server key` from `CLOUD MESSEGING` Tab.

In my case, it was worked like charm.

happy coding
 :-)

Comment: I am using the server key right now.
Same result :(