# How to achieve push notification in cordova app using php?

Tags: php, cordova, push-notification

I have written this code for achieving push notification. But I am getting error. I have no idea where I am doing mistake.

```
<?php

// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAADp9idX0:APA91bGHN3PP5GKS3OnVdRQgyNgx-bvAvIoR86B0e_NcZ6XP7QvLNoMiTtO54pB1PbtA3tQo5xuxmfIXD9E40oBnkXcZs9OZKSHXFASO0aH8dv7RozYuvjQXL7rguyHmuIdhOCbg' );

$registrationIds = array('62803502086');

//$registrationIds = '62803572093';
// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;
?>
```

Getting this error in browser screen-

> {"multicast_id":2810501046743574091,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

Comment: check this please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29705993/using-gcm-to-send-notifications-on-app-returns-invalidregistration-error

Answer (score 0):

Please check if 62803502086 is a valid registration/push id.
You can check for your device's registration using the below plugin
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/EXAMPLES.md .

Notice

```
 push.on('registration', (data) => {
//var reg_id= data.registrationId
```

});

you may log the registration id and use it in your php api.

Comment: Phone Push notifications Plugin doesn't support the latest Cordova version 10X.
To get Push notifications for Android and IOS using Frirebase ,we need to use cordova-plugin-firebasex               .https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I prefer using cordova plugin named "**PUSHER**".
when you working with manual pusher and compile it with cordova normally you must achieve Device ID of device using your app.I tried achieving DeviceId in Cordova but no success and return empty and seems happen because of security purpose.

For Better and quick result of push notification follow instructions [Here](https://pusher.com/tutorials/updates-native-push-notifications-cordova) for using PUSHER.(In a section of article described

> Blockquote

that you must register your app with APN Servers ex: Google Developer Account and achieve regstration id from google cloud

> Blockquote

so generating or finding id failed for many reason like too long byte id which failed in transmitions between app and server)

*Hope to be helpful.*

Pusher : https://pusher.com/tutorials/updates-native-push-notifications-cordova